# Is there a word or phrase in Chinese referring to the physical office of Chinese authority?

Tags: word-requests

In other countries, when referring to government offices, they use interesting words:

US: White House, Capitol Hill, Oval Office, Pentagon

UK: No.10 Downing Street. Scotland Yard,Buckingham Palace, Westminster Abbey

Russia: Kremlin

South Korea: Blue House

France: Elysee Palace

North Korea: Kumsusan Palace of the Sun

Japan：Yasukuni Shrine

Is there the same for China?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no specific building/address like 白宮，克里姆林宮 or 唐寧街十號 is used to represent a government. The name of the capital of a country is usually used.

Capitals like 北京, 東京, 渥太華 (Beijing, Tokyo, Ottawa) are commonly used to  refer to the governments of  China, Japan, and Canada

In the case of China, [中南海](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%8D%97%E6%B5%B7/6947) (国家政务办公处)- Zhongnanhai (National Government Affairs Office) is comparable to The White House, Kremlin and No.10 Downing Street. It is where the power of the government is represented.

> [中南海](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%8D%97%E6%B5%B7/6947)现为中华人民共和国的国家中枢，最高行政权力的象征和代名词

> Zhongnanhai is now the national center of the People’s Republic of China, a symbol and synonym of the highest administrative power

We also use the office of the highest administrative officer to refer to the government, e.g. 椭圆形公室 (The Oval office = the president's office); 內閣總理大臣辨公室 (Office of the Prime Minister)

Answer (score 1):

**Zhongnanhai** is a former imperial garden in the Imperial City, Beijing, adjacent to the Forbidden City; it serves as the central headquarters for the Chinese Communist Party (CCP) and the State Council (Central government) of China. Zhongnanhai houses the office of the General Secretary of the Chinese Communist Party (paramount leader) and Premier of the People's Republic of China. The term Zhongnanhai is closely linked with the central government and senior Communist Party officials. It is often used as a metonym for the Chinese leadership at large, in the same sense that the term "White House" refers to the U.S. executive branch.

**The Great Hall of the People** in Beijing. The National People's Congress (NPC) is theoretically the highest body within the Chinese Communist Party. Since 1987 the National Congress has been held in the months of October or November. The venue for the event, beginning in 1956, is the Great Hall of the People in Beijing. (Wikipedia)

Note that the President of the People's Republic of China, is the ceremonial head of state of the People's Republic of China (PRC). Under the current PRC Constitution, the presidency is a largely ceremonial office with very limited power.[2] However, since 1993, as a matter of convention, the presidency has been held simultaneously by the General Secretary of the Chinese Communist Party, the top leader of this one-party state. The presidency is officially regarded as an institution of the state rather than an administrative post; theoretically, the president serves at the pleasure of the National People's Congress (NPC), the legislature, and is not legally vested to take executive action on his own prerogative.